# Variable initialized but not recognized?

Tags: java, foreach, initialization

Hey I am a high school and I found the solution to my problem but confused on why it's doing what it's doing can someone explain? Also I tried looking for the answer but couldn't find it so sorry if someone's already answered this.

So at `getAverage()` I state int i; and initialize it in the foreach loop but when it runs it says `"variable i might not have been initialized"`? I found the solution to this was just make `int i = 0;` but i'm confused because I know you can state a variable and not initialize it at that time as long as you initialize it later. So what makes this so special?

```
public class ArrayAverage
{
   private int[] values;

   public ArrayAverage(int[] theValues)
   {
      values = theValues;
   }

   public double getAverage()
   {
       // Problem here
       int i; // Solution: int i = 0;
       for(int value : values){
           i += value;
       }
       double avg = (double)i / values.length;
       return avg;
   }
}
```

---

```
// This pseudo code code has nothing to do with above code
// but is example of what I know can be done but isn't 

int i;
i = 10;
System.out.println(i);
//Output would be 10
```

Comment: `i += value` assumes that the variable `i` _has_ been initialized at that point, which it is not.

Comment: Omg I feel dumb now idk why I was confused now I wish I didn't post this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the you're adding the variable `i` to itself, and another value. However, the initial value for `i` has not been defined in the previous code. This is the reason that `i = 0` would make the code work, as the program now understands that for the first loop, it has to add the value to 0, then the second loop will know to add the previous value, to the new value.

Hope this helped.